# variable in generic class cannot be represented in objective c

Tags: ios, generics, swift

Trying to create a generic ViewControlelr that takes a model type and handle pagination, etc.
Getting the following error. Is there a workaround for this?

**Variable in generic class cannot be represented in Objective-C**

```
class BasePaginatingViewController<T: BaseModel>: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no generics in Objective-C unless you want to use C++ templates which are strongly discourage.

The closest you can get in Objective-C is passing as 'id' and than confirming whether its the kind of object you recognize by one of the below:

```
  if([o respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod)]) {
    [o myMethod];

  if([o conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)]) {
    [o myMethod];

  if ([o isKindOfClass:MyClass.class]) {
  // do something.
  }
```

---

> **But If you really want to do it... Follow this:**

http://overooped.com/post/22516989979/tctypesafety

Comment: How does this answer solve the problem? It's Swift not Obj-C. (I know that Obj-C not supporting generics is the root of this problem but the suggested solutions are Obj-C only, that doesn't help here).

Comment: I guess u misunderstood the question. Question was asked about Objective-C giving reference to swift sample. Objective-C just supports lightweight generics compared to extensive support by swift.

Comment: The error as described in the question is from a Swift-only code basis. The fact that it is caused by Obj-C not supporting generics is rather an internal, and providing code snippets in Obj-C doesn't help since the question or any other code getting this error is not using Obj-C. Unless you want to mix Swift and Obj-C but that doesn't seem to be the case.